# SQL get all Rows with Value VB.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, cursor, office-interop

I have developed a word export function within my VB.net application which returns all rows that have a specific value in the column (service_name). However when looping through the function the cells in word always grabs the first service name instead of cycling through each one. I need a way in which I can point to the next value for the specific service_name.

[image]

[image]

I have given previews of the table I am grabing the value from and the word export knowing that there are 3 rows which match the value but always returning the first one.

Function used for returning SQL data:

```
Function getdataapplication(ByVal recordnum As Integer, ByVal fieldnum As Integer)
        ds.Reset()
        GC.Collect()

        Dim dbtable
        dbtable = "application_portfolio"

        Dim sql As MySqlCommand

        sql = New MySqlCommand("Select * from application_portfolio where service_name = '" & Wordexport.tbservicename.Text & "' ", dbcon)

        Dim DataAdapter1 As MySqlDataAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter()
        DataAdapter1.SelectCommand = sql


        DataAdapter1.Fill(ds, dbtable)
        dbcon.Close()
        sql.Dispose()
        Return ds.Tables(dbtable).rows(recordnum).Item(fieldnum - 1)
            'Return reader
    End Function

Public Sub Word_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Word.Click

        Dim sqlrowcount As Integer
        sqlrowcount = CountRecords()
        tbcount.Text = sqlrowcount

        If application_portfolio.Checked = True Then
            'oWord.NewDocument.Application.Equals(Nothing)
            Dim oPara2application As Word.Paragraph
            Dim oTableapplication As Word.Table

            For i As Integer = 1 To sqlrowcount
                j = j + 1
                oTableapplication = oDoc.Tables.Add(oDoc.Bookmarks.Item("\endofdoc").Range, j, 7)
                oTableapplication.Range.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 6
                oTableapplication.Rows(1).Range.Font.Bold = True
                oTableapplication.Cell(1, 1).Range.Text = "ID"
                oTableapplication.Cell(1, 2).Range.Text = "Service Name"
                oTableapplication.Cell(1, 3).Range.Text = "Application Name"
                oTableapplication.Cell(1, 4).Range.Text = "Application Type"
                oTableapplication.Cell(1, 5).Range.Text = "Cost"
                oTableapplication.Cell(1, 6).Range.Text = "Year Released"
                oTableapplication.Cell(1, 7).Range.Text = "Version"

                Dim tempdatastore = getdataapplication(0, 1)
                ListBox1.Items.Add(tempdatastore)
                oTableapplication.Cell(j, 1).Range.Text = functions.getdataapplication(0, 1)
                oTableapplication.Cell(j, 2).Range.Text = functions.getdataapplication(0, 2)
                oTableapplication.Cell(j, 3).Range.Text = functions.getdataapplication(0, 3)
                oTableapplication.Cell(j, 4).Range.Text = functions.getdataapplication(0, 4)
                oTableapplication.Cell(j, 5).Range.Text = functions.getdataapplication(0, 5)
                oTableapplication.Cell(j, 6).Range.Text = functions.getdataapplication(0, 6)
                oTableapplication.Cell(j, 7).Range.Text = functions.getdataapplication(0, 7)
                oTableapplication.Rows.Item(1).Range.Font.Italic = True
            Next
        End If
End function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem of your error. you keep on search for row 0 in your function getdataapplication

```
oTableapplication.Cell(j, 1).Range.Text = functions.getdataapplication(0, 1)
oTableapplication.Cell(j, 2).Range.Text = functions.getdataapplication(0, 2)
oTableapplication.Cell(j, 3).Range.Text = functions.getdataapplication(0, 3)
oTableapplication.Cell(j, 4).Range.Text = functions.getdataapplication(0, 4)
oTableapplication.Cell(j, 5).Range.Text = functions.getdataapplication(0, 5)
oTableapplication.Cell(j, 6).Range.Text = functions.getdataapplication(0, 6)
oTableapplication.Cell(j, 7).Range.Text = functions.getdataapplication(0, 7)
```

What you need to do is as follows

```
oTableapplication.Cell(j, 1).Range.Text = functions.getdataapplication(i, 1)
oTableapplication.Cell(j, 2).Range.Text = functions.getdataapplication(i, 2)
oTableapplication.Cell(j, 3).Range.Text = functions.getdataapplication(i, 3)
oTableapplication.Cell(j, 4).Range.Text = functions.getdataapplication(i, 4)
oTableapplication.Cell(j, 5).Range.Text = functions.getdataapplication(i, 5)
oTableapplication.Cell(j, 6).Range.Text = functions.getdataapplication(i, 6)
oTableapplication.Cell(j, 7).Range.Text = functions.getdataapplication(i, 7)
```

Comment: Thank you it worked :)
I also had to change             For i As Integer = 0 To sqlrowcount -1

Answer (score 0):

Every time you call `getdataapplication`, you are passing the value `0` for the `recordnum` parameter.  Therefore, it is always going to output the data from the first row.  Inside your `For` loop, you probably want to be using `i` instead of `0`, for instance:

```
Dim tempdatastore = getdataapplication(i, 1)
```

However, this seems like a really terrible design.  Every time you are calling the `getdataapplication` method, which happens multiple times per iteration of the loop, it is both forcing the garbage collector to do its thing *AND* re-querying the database.  It would make *far* more sense to query the database once and then loop through the contents of the returned `DataSet`.  It's doubtful that you should not need to call `GC.Collect`.

Comment: Thank you, I will try and find a better solution.